# Image classification - coloring features with a colormap?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

I have an image with some features/regions in it (*balls* in the above example). I want to color each ball with a different color based on its properties. For example, that might be its diameter in pixels.

While I'm done on the feature recognition side, I'm stuck when it comes to showing results. Right now I'm doing:

```
my_image = imread(...);

//ball recognition and other stuff

for i = 1:number_of_balls
   ball_diameter(i) = ... //I calculate the diameter of the i-th ball
   ball_indices = ... //I get the linear indices of the i-th ball

   //ball coloring
   my_image(ball_indices) = 255; //color the red channel
   my_image(ball_indices + R*C) = 0; //color the blue channel
   my_image(ball_indices + 2*R*C) = 0; //color the green channel
end

figure
imshow(my_image)
colormap jet(100) //I want 100 different classes
colorbar
caxis([0, 50]) //I assume all balls have a diameter < 50
```

In the above code I'm tinting all balls red, which is definitely not what I'm looking for. The issue is that, even if I know `ball_diameter(i)`, I do not know which `colormap` class that ball will get in. In other words, I would need something like:

```
for i = 1:number_of_balls
   // ...

   if ball_diameter *belongs to class k*
      my_image(ball_indices) = jet(k, 1);
      my_image(ball_indices + R*C) = jet(k,2);
      my_image(ball_indices + 2*R*C) = jet(k,3);
   end
end
```

How to, and mostly, is there any other more logical way?

Comment: So whats your problem? creating the classes? or creating the colormaps?

Comment: Do you not decide yourself which colourmap a ball will get assigned to? What is wrong with the last `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the assignment of pixels to classes from their coloring for display: you can use `my_image` as a 2D `R`-by-`C` labeling matrix: that is each object (ball) is assigned a different *index* from 1 to 100 (in case you have 100 objects in the image). Now when you want to **display** the result you can either ask the figure to map indexes to colors for you, using `colormap` or explicitly create a colored image using [`ind2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html).

For example

```
%// create the index/labeling matrix
my_image = zeros( R, C );
for ii = 1:number_of_balls
    my_image( ball_indices ) = ii; %// assign index to pixels and not atual colors
end

%// color using figure
figure;
imagesc( my_image );axis image; 
colormap rand(100,3); %// map indexes to colors using random mapping

%//explicitly create a color image using ind2rgb
my_color_image = ind2rgb( my_image, rand(100,3) );
figure;
imshow( my_color_image ); % display the color image
```

Notes:
1. IMHO it is preferable to use random color map to display categorizations of pixels, as opposed to `jet` with which you usually end up with very similar colors to adjacent objects, making it very difficult to visually appreciate the result.
2. IMHO it is more convenient to use label matrix, you can also save it to file as an indexed image (png format) thus visualizing, saving and loading your results simply and efficiently.

Comment: My issue at this point is that this way I lose the greyscale information in non-ball regions of the image (maybe the example pic I posted is quite unclear about this); I need to deal with regions that *are not* belonging to a ball, and I would like to have them shown in greyscale (while balls are shown in different colors). See also my comments to the other answer. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Thinking about it, maybe I could just set `my_color_image(*non classified pixels*)` to the corresponding pixels in `my_original_greyscale_image`. Seems promising, will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is as follows:

1. Make a 2D image of the same size as your original.
2. Set the indices of each "ball" to the diameter or other relevant value
3. Display with `imagesc`
4. Use `caxis`, `colormap`, `colorbar` etc. to adjust the categories dynamically.

For example,

```
a = randi(200,200); % 200 x 200 image containing values 1 to 200 at random
imagesc(a)
colorbar
```

The above should show a random color field with the default colormap. The colorbar goes from 1 to 200.

```
colormap(jet(5))
```

The colorbar still goes from 1 to 200, but with only 5 colors.

```
caxis([1 100])
```

The colorbar now shows the five colors scaled from 1 to 100 (with everything above 100 in the top pot).

If you want to convert your 2D image full of different diameters to a set of discrete labels indicating diameter ranges, an easy way is to use `histc` with the second output `bin` being the same size as your input image, set to which bin the diameter value fell into.  The second input in this case is the *edges* of the bins, not the centres.

```
[n bin] = histc(a,0:20:201);
```

Comment: I get your point, and this way I will have a new blank image with just the "balls" in it. My issue in this case is that all non-ball regions of my original image get lost. My wish is to have a background (greyscale if necessary) image, and above this image the colored, colorbar-ed representation of the balls.

Comment: I would then need to combine your `a` [big matrix with diameters in correspondence of balls, and 0s elsewhere, to be shown with `imagesc(a)`] with my `my_image` [greyscale picture, to be shown with `imshow`]. I don't know how I could do it.

Comment: (Promising clue just came from other answer [`ind2rgb(a)`])